# Custom UIBarButtonItem tint Color wrong for Mail and Messages only

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller

My overall app's theme is blue with white text. Everywhere in the app presents properly with the exceptions of Messages and Mail being presented via a UIActionViewController sheet.

Once those two load, everything looks correct *except* the bar button items aren't white like they should be—they're blue and very hard to see since the bar is blue.

Behaves good here:
[image: It works fine in the app]

But not here when Messages or Mail is displayed via UIActivityViewController:
[image: But looks like this via UIActivityViewController in Messages and Mail]

I have tried setting this in my AppDelegate but it does not help:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.classForCoder()]).tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Any ideas as to whether this is a bug or if I should try something else? I've searched through many threads and nothing seems to solve this issue.

Thank you!

### EDIT:

I was able to fix the Messages tint colour, but *not* the Mail tint colour...I extended the viewWillAppear methods of both using the exact same code, but it creates different results in each (doesn't make sense to me!). Must be a bug with the MFMailComposeViewController??

```
extension MFMailComposeViewController {
  public override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  }

  public override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
  }

  public override func childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle() -> UIViewController? {
    return nil
  }
}

extension MFMessageComposeViewController {
  public override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  }

  public override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
  }

  public override func childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle() -> UIViewController? {
    return nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it to much effort to style every single navbar with the white bar button and you want to set the style in one line of code or you don't know how to style them?

Comment: I've already done that using .appearance() and it's fine everywhere else. It's just that it doesn't work once Mail or Messages are brought up via the activityviewcontroller.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

For your button which you want to change the background color to white, try to apply this code in the controller you want it to be:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: The navigation bar is already blue...it's the bar button items that are blue but should be white. They appear white everywhere else in my app except these two areas via the activityviewcontroller sheet. My app already has set all navigationBars to have white bar button items and it displays correctly.

Comment: I assume you have an outlet in your code what if you are trying to set the backgrouncolor of the button in your code?

Comment: The problem is I have no direct access to the bar button elements that activityviewcontroller displays. It's all handled by the OS via the activityviewcontroller.